# What should I do if I see someone not picking up after their dog in a "pick up after your dog" zone?

Tags: california, pets

I've repeatedly seen owners not pick up feces after their dog on a street, well in proximity of a sign "All pet feces must be removed" and public bags for pet feces as well as a trash can for it.

What should I do? Sometimes I am with a camera(sightseeing, my phone) and I could take evidence with it.

Is it legal to film that (on a public street)?
If it is, and I get evidence that the owner saw the dog pooping, and walked away back to her apartment, passing the public bags, like nothing happened, what should I do? Tell the police, go to court, or tell apartment admin (I think they put the signs)?

Comment: Have you tried taking a bag, cleaning up the poop, giving the bag to them and politely telling them they dropped something? The folks that my husband has done that to were never repeat offenders within sight of our yard, but we weren’t in a very densely populated neighborhood.

Comment: You could be helpful and let them know those poop cleanup bags are provided for free to the public, so they don’t have to run home and get their own bags like you know they were just about to do. About half the people I confront for stuff like that respond well to the assumption that they were of course going to do the right thing, but they’re just got distracted, weren’t sure they could take a bag etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not really a question of law.

Comment: This is a question of proper procedure when one witnesses an apparent violation of law, and so is on-topic.

Comment: This could be on-topic if it asked a specific question about the legal procedure for reporting a violation (as @DavidSiegel suggests), whether the signs are legally enforceable, whether you can compel the complex to enforce it, etc.  But "what should I do?" is not a legal question, especially if the options include asking the apartment complex to email everyone, which has nothing to do with the law.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a Law SE and not about interpersonal relations, manners or other topics I will focus on the legal options.

There are a number of actions pertaining to publicizing the event that are legal, such as filming and posting, describing and tweeting, writing letters to the editor and so on. Your main legal concern would be making a false defamatory statement, such as claiming that Bill Smith did this when it wasn't Bill Smith. This could certainly include notifying the property owner. "Public discussion" is always possible, even if the other person's action is entirely legal.

Notifying the police is an exception w.r.t. defamation, in that you can't be sued for defamation if you mistakenly accuse Smith of doing this. However, police generally will not get involved unless there is a violation of the law (some city scooping ordinance) on city property, if the ordinance is actively enforced.

Unless you are the property owner, you cannot sue the person for damages, because he hasn't harmed you.

Comment: In some jurisdictions scooping ordinances apply, and wil be enforced, on private property as well as public. I was an observer of a case where a citizen reported an (alleged) failure to scoop on private property (not the dog owner's property) and the police filed misdemeanor  (or it may have been infraction) charges and the matter went to trial. Of course the police were influenced by the reporting citizen, who was the then mayor of the small town involved, and who had a political feud with the dog walker.